# MongoDB-Mongoose Typescript Generic Requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, generics, mongoose

I'm creating a helper class for all my database functions with MongoDB. While I'm doing it, I thought if it's possible to create Generic database functions for MongoDB with mongoose.
I tested a little bit, but didn't come to a result. 
I'm using like I mentioned [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/) with [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) in combination with Typescript.

```
export async function getByID<T>(id: string): Promise<T> {
    const found: T = await T.findById(id);
    return found;
}
```

My codeexample is not working right now, but it should demonstrate what I want to achive. I hope you guys can help me.